# Paperclip Resize and Crop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, image-resizing

I am using Paperclip with Rails4. I have the following image

[image]

Now i want to resize and Crop the image but its getting cropped and orientation of the image is getting displaced like below

[image]

```
:photo,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :styles => {
        :small => { :geometry => "100x100!" },
        :medium => { :geometry => "500x500!"}
}
```

Comment: this comment isnt the answer but a suggestion. you should checkout out cloudinary. the images need not be processed on your server but cloudinary processes them and serves them for you. You just store a single image on cloudinary. whenever you require a image in the application, you can specify the custom size of the image with the specific orientation and cloudinary will process your saved image on the fly and serve the new image.

Comment: have u used it with rails?

Comment: yes. with rails 4. checkout http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration. the biggest plus point is that i can get images with any size i want anytime. with paperclip n server side processing, i have to reprocess all the images and then use them and for that i need to install libraries on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [ImageMagic resize docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/). You probably need to use `100x100#` instead of `100x100!`

Comment: i tried that. its working better. but instead of getting 100x100 i am getting 100x67 any idea how to resize and crop?

Comment: My bad, sorry. Use `100x100#`

Comment: This is live working code to do what you want: `:square => "120x120#" `